# Deploy Rails App on Ubuntu 12 Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I am completely new to deploying code to server.
Can someone provide me with steps to deploy my ruby app which I have at present deployed in Heroku.
I am using Rails 3.2. and would like to deploy it to my ubuntu 12 server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html